# Jquery form submission using AJAX and PHP on the page page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn form submission with AJAX and Jquery. I have put together some resources to do it. These include separate files/pages for jquery, HTML, and php. Everything works as intended when all of these files are in separate pages and linked through reference in the head tags. But when I put all codes from these files on the same page, index.php, I get an error. Namely 'Could not reach server, please try again later'. This is the error jquery prints when the form submission fails.

Please point out what I need to change so that I can submit and process the form and echo results on the same page, index.php. Thank you very much for your time.
Here is what I have so far in the index.php file which is the file that contains everything.

```html
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
      //ob_clean();

    $errors = [];
    $data = [];

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
    }

    if (empty($_POST['superheroAlias'])) {
        $errors['superheroAlias'] = 'Superhero alias is required.';
    }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors'] = $errors;
    } else {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

    //exit;
  }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Form Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="form.js"></script>-->

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
            var formData = {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                superheroAlias: $("#superheroAlias").val(),
            };
        
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                encode: true,
            }).done(function (data) {
                //console.log(data);

                if (!data.success) {
                    if (data.errors.name) {
                    $("#name-group").addClass("has-error");
                    $("#name-group").append(
                        '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + "</div>"
                    );
                    }
            
                    if (data.errors.email) {
                    $("#email-group").addClass("has-error");
                    $("#email-group").append(
                        '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + "</div>"
                    );
                    }
            
                    if (data.errors.superheroAlias) {
                    $("#superhero-group").addClass("has-error");
                    $("#superhero-group").append(
                        '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.superheroAlias + "</div>"
                    );
                    }
                } else {
                    $("form").html(
                    '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>"
                    );
                }

            })    .fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        // Our error logic here
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        $('#post').html(msg);
    })

            
            
            
            /*.fail(function (data) {
                $("form").html(
                '<div class="alert alert-danger">Could not reach server, please try again later.</div>'
                );
            });*/
            
        
            event.preventDefault();

            $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(".help-block").remove();
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <h1>Processing an AJAX Form</h1>
        <h4 id="post"></h4>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
        </div>

        <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" />
        </div>

        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="superheroAlias">Superhero Alias</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="superheroAlias" name="superheroAlias" placeholder="Ant Man, Wonder Woman, Black Panther, Superman, Black Widow" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's the error message you're seeing because that's the error message you're explicitly outputting to the page.  You need to find out what the *actual* error is.  In the `.fail()` callback, what is the value of `data`?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  On the network tab, what is the result of the AJAX operation?

Comment: Just put your php code who is above the html in another file like /ajax/index.php and change the targeted file in your jQuery call. this php code call by ajax return your data and you get the result form it.

Comment: @David, thanks for looking into my question. I am fairly new to coding. I do not know how the debugging through inspect elements actually work. But when I check out the console and network tabs, there are no errors. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @StéphaneM, Thanks for looking into my question. I wanted to be able to collect form data, process them in PHP and echo them out in the same index.php. I did not quite get what you meant by putting the code into another file and changing the targeted file in jQUery call.

Comment: @peeKatU: No errors at all even after the AJAX operation?  What about the respnose from the server in the network tab?  What is that response body and is it what you expect?  The jQuery code is specifically expecting JSON in the response.  Is that what the server is returning?

Comment: @David, Thanks for replying. When you mentioned fail() callback, I did  a little digging into the function and found out that I have a JSON PARSE ERROR of some kind. I updated my index.php file. Please take a look at it. Thank you

Comment: @peeKatU: That most likely means the response from the server is *not* valid JSON.  Note that keeping your functionality in separate files like you describe at the start of the question is an ideal way to avoid this problem.  But if you want everything in the same file then you have to conditionally determine whether that file outputs JSON data or the HTML page, but never both.

Comment: @David Thanks a lot David. I learned very helpful things today with your help.